# How to build a sql query to return avg(price), min(price), max(price) joined with avg(order), min(order), max(order)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to create a sql query that returns results together for 2 different queries. For example, I'd like to have results in the form of:
Product Name, avg(price), min(price), max(price), avg(order), min(order), max(order)
At the moment I have 2 sql queries of the form:

```
select 
  product.name, order.id, avg(price), min(price), max(price) 
from 
  product, order 
where
  product.name = order.product_name and product.name = 'price' 
group by 
  product.name, order.id

select 
  product.name, order.id, avg(order), min(order), max(order) 
from 
  product, order 
where 
  product.name = order.product_name and product.name = 'order' 
group by 
  product.name, order.id
```

Some products have a price and an order, others have only a price, and others have only and order. How do I write a query that will display all the results and join those that have both an order and a price and display those that have both as i row?

Comment: This question really needs `create table` statements and sample data. The queries provided simply don't make much sense, so some context is badly needed. Also, as written, these queries are syntactically invalid: `order` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an object name unless it is enclosed in double-quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is a full outer join since rows could be in either one table or the other or both:

```
SELECT 
   NVL(t1.name,t2.name) as name,
   NVL(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
   avg_price,
   min_price,
   max_price,
   avg_order,
   min_order,
   max_order
FROM 
(select product.name, order.id, avg(price) as avg_price, min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price 
from product, order 
where product.name = order.product_name and product.name = 'price' 
group by product.name, order.id) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(select product.name, order.id, avg(order) as avg_order, min(order) as min_order, max(order) as max_order
from product, order 
where product.name = order.product_name and product.name = 'order' 
group by product.name, order.id) t2
ON t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: I would guess  you want to add `AND t1.id = t2.id` to the join condition.

Comment: @Dave - could be, I'm not really sure though. it seemed like he was joining product and order based on the product name, so I'm assuming that was his primary key.

Comment: How would I make it so that product.name & order.id only show up once, and make sure it is not null? At the moment results contain 2 columns for product.name & 2 for order.id. In the case that 1 is null, I'd like the non-null one to be displayed. In the case that they're the same, only 1 needs to be displayed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Alessandro - Updated my answer to include how to do that (using NVL to choose the name/id that isn't null)

Answer (score 0):

Your queries don't make a whole lot of sense, so there's a lot I had to attempt to infer from your question. It's always better to post the `create table` scripts and some sample data (as well as the desired output) when asking SQL questions.

Below is a scenario I created that attempts to recreate your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE product(id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE orders(product_name VARCHAR2(10), VALUE NUMBER);

INSERT INTO product
VALUES     (1, 'order');    
INSERT INTO product
VALUES     (1, 'price');    
INSERT INTO product
VALUES     (2, 'order');    
INSERT INTO product
VALUES     (3, 'price');    
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES     ('order', 5);    
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES     ('price', 5);    
COMMIT;
```

Given this scenario, the following query will provide 3 rows, with the "order" and/or "price" columns populated where appropriate.

```
SELECT   p.id,
         AVG(o1.VALUE) as avg_price,
         MIN(o1.VALUE) as min_price,
         MAX(o1.VALUE) as max_price,
         AVG(o2.VALUE) as avg_order,
         MIN(o2.VALUE) as min_order,
         MAX(o2.VALUE) as max_order
FROM             product p
         LEFT JOIN orders o1
              ON p.name = o1.product_name AND p.name = 'price'
         LEFT JOIN orders o2
              ON p.name = o2.product_name AND p.name = 'order'
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually over simplified the table structure but since it's not open source I had to. This definitely helped.